# If XXX, the system will do A rather than "do"/"does"/"doing" B?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

- If XXX, the (software) system will do A rather than do B.
- If XXX, the (software) system will do A rather than does B.
- If XXX, the (software) system will do A rather than doing B.

Which one is correct or better?

Update:
If there is a comma before "rather than", such as:

> If the system is overloaded, the task scheduler will fall into a
>   "conservation mode", rather than unconditionally
>   follow/follows/following the user-specified rules.

Which one is better?

Comment: The most natural would be, “If XXX, the system will do A rather than B”. No need to repeat the verb at all.

Comment: If there is a comma before "rather than", such as: If the system is overloaded, the task scheduler will fall into a "conservation mode", rather than unconditionally follow/follows/following the user-specified rules. Which one is better?

Answer (score 2):

1 and 3 are both possible. Grammatically they're different (1 has "rather than" introducing a finite clause, with a parallellism to the main clause; in 3 it introduces a noun phrase with a gerund as its head) but I find them equally acceptable, and pretty well synonymous.

Comment: If there is a comma before "rather than", such as: If the system is overloaded, the task scheduler will fall into a "conservation mode", rather than unconditionally follow/follows/following the user-specified rules. Which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

`If XXX, the (software) system will do A rather than do B.` is correct. An easy rule of thumb is that the conjugation of the verb (if the verbs are the same) will most always be the same in this kind of situation.

Comment: If there is a comma before "rather than", such as: If the system is overloaded, the task scheduler will fall into a "conservation mode", rather than unconditionally follow/follows/following the user-specified rules. Which one is better?